# Xamarin: Reopening causes "NU1202" error?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my Xamarin app here, when I reopen it, it gaves me a NU1202 error and I can't solve.I can't also update packages or install new ones. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: 1202 is a compatibly issue, but without the details of the error, no one can really help. Add the full error as formatted text to your question.

Comment: ok that's it                                                                                                      Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package Validate 1.0.3 is not compatible with monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0). Package Validate 1.0.3 supports: net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)

Comment: Did it work fine sometime early?

Comment: yes ,  it worked